# Playing audio data in React from Node/Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, audio-streaming

I am currently working on a feature that would allow streaming audio files in React from my Node server.

I set up the server side so the GET route returns this way :

```
res.set('content-type', 'audio/mp3');
res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');

file.createReadStream().on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({message: "Couldn't read file" })
}).on("data", (chunk) => {
    res.write(chunk);
}).on("end", () => {
    res.end();
})
```

When testing with postman, this works perfectly to get the audio (but not as streaming obviously).

I am now wondering what would be the best way to handle the response on the client side. I am currently using Axios to communicate with the backend. I would like to be able to play the audio as soon as some data is available from the response.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you should check out websockets, i think this fits better to your case

Comment: @IsaToltar That would be bad advice.  HTTP as-is can easily be used for streaming, and the browser can handle it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement).  It will handle all the streaming aspects for you, including the HTTP request, buffering, decoding, and playback.

On the server-side, you'll need to support ranged requests.  The easiest thing to do here is use `express.static()`, since you're not generating the data dynamically.

Comment: It seems to work fine with this solution! Indeed, I just provide the url and the HTMLAudioElement does everything. I did not use express.static() as I'm getting the data from a cloud storage with node.
Thanks!

Comment: @antostene Cool, glad to help.  If you'd like, you can check the mark next to this answer to mark it as resolved.  Also, which cloud storage are you using?  If S3 or similar, it's best to sign URLs and let the browser request them directly rather than proxying.  Far cheaper that way, and more efficient.

Comment: I am using gcloud storage for this. The thing is that I don't want these files to be accessible for anyone, but only by my app. Would that be possible without proxying ?

Comment: @antostene Yes.  Your server can sign the URLs and send them to the client.  The client can only access them for a short time.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: That seems far better than my current solution indeed. I'll dig into that thank you so much !